# How can I make org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter throw an exception instead of printing errors to stderr?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I am currently utilizing `org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter` for bytecode verification in my Java project. However, I've observed that this class prints errors to stderr instead of throwing exceptions, which makes it challenging to handle verification failures programmatically.

Here is an example of the existing code snippet:

```java
final byte[] bytes = …; // class bytes are generated previously  
CheckClassAdapter.verify(
    new ClassReader(bytes),
    false,
    new PrintWriter(System.err)
);
```

It appears that a potential workaround could be:

```java
final byte[] bytes = …; // class bytes are generated previously  
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
CheckClassAdapter.verify(
    new ClassReader(bytes),
    false,
    pw
);
if (sw.toString().contains("AnalyzerException")) {
  System.err.println(sw.toString());
  fail();
}
```

However, this solution feels like a "crutch" to me. Is there a way to modify or extend the `CheckClassAdapter` to make it throw an exception when bytecode verification fails, rather than printing errors to stderr? I aim to catch and handle verification errors within my code. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

---

[ASM](https://asm.ow2.io) version: `org.ow2.asm:asm:9.6`

Comment: `CheckClassAdapter` does throw an exception already. It’s a specific behavior of the static `verify` method to catch that `AnalyzerException` and produce the textual output. Just look into [the source code of the `verify` method](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/-/blob/master/asm-util/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/util/CheckClassAdapter.java?ref_type=heads#L1044). When you remove everything you don’t need, you end up with less than twenty lines. But keep in mind that class visitors can be chained, you can integrate the checking into the code generation instead of parsing the result afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I haven't found how I can use `CheckClassAdapter` to verify bytecode and throw an `AnalyzerException` exception, I decided to modify [the source code of the verify method](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/-/blob/master/asm-util/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/util/CheckClassAdapter.java?ref_type=heads#L1044), as [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) suggested. Here's how you can verify the bytecode:

```java
/**
 * Verify the bytecode.
 * @param bytes The bytecode to verify.
 */
private void verify(final byte[] bytes) throws AnalyzerException {
    final ClassNode clazz = new ClassNode();
    new ClassReader(bytes)
        .accept(new CheckClassAdapter(clazz, false), ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG);
    final Optional<Type> syper = Optional.ofNullable(clazz.superName).map(Type::getObjectType);
    final List<Type> interfaces = clazz.interfaces.stream().map(Type::getObjectType)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (final MethodNode method : clazz.methods) {
        final SimpleVerifier verifier =
            new SimpleVerifier(
                Type.getObjectType(clazz.name),
                syper.orElse(null),
                interfaces,
                (clazz.access & Opcodes.ACC_INTERFACE) != 0
            );
        // You might need to set your own ClassLoader here.
        // verifier.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        new Analyzer<>(verifier).analyze(clazz.name, method);
    }
}
```

Imports:

```java
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;
import org.objectweb.asm.Type;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException;
import org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.SimpleVerifier;
import org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter;
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that this method isn't perfect since you generate bytecode and then parse it again. Most probably, you can simplify this process by integrating bytecode verification directly into the generation process using `CheckClassAdapter` and `CheckMethodAdapter` classes